# Обращение к функции

Tags: php, echo

Функция содержит конструкцию из нескольких строк `echo`. Строки будут выводится по 2, поэтому разделены на блоки.

**Функция:**

```
function add_block() {

$text1 = 'текст1';
$text2 = 'текст2';

// блок 1
echo '<p class="block-one">' . $text1 . '</p>' . "\n";
echo '<p class="block-two">' . $text2 . '</p>' . "\n";

// блок 2
echo '<p class="block-three">' . $text1 . '</p>' . "\n";
echo '<p class="block-four">' . $text2 . '</p>' . "\n";

// блок 3
echo '<p class="block-five">' . $text1 . '</p>' . "\n";
echo '<p class="block-six">' . $text2 . '</p>' . "\n";

}
```

Что нужно сделать чтобы вывести строки из функции?

Например я пишу `<?php echo add_block($blockone); ?>` и вывелись строки только из первого блока.

```
// блок 1
echo '<p class="block-one">' . $text1 . '</p>' . "\n";
echo '<p class="block-two">' . $text2 . '</p>' . "\n";
```

`<?php echo add_block($blocktwo); ?>` - из второго блока и т.д...

Comment: как-то странно видеть в блоке 1 - блоки 1 и 2, а в блоке 2 - блоки 3 и 4....вам не кажется это бредово выглядит? Классы (block-one, block-two и прочие) уже завязаны на css или прочую логику? Или это просто как-то визуально отделено здесь? чем они отличаются например?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addBlock($block){
    switch((int)$block){
        case 1:
            $out = '<p class="block-one">' . $text1 . '</p>' . "\n";
            $out .= '<p class="block-two">' . $text1 . '</p>' . "\n";
        break;
        case 2:
            $out = '<p class="block-three">' . $text1 . '</p>' . "\n";
            $out .= '<p class="block-four">' . $text1 . '</p>' . "\n";
        break;
        default:
            $out = '<p class="error">Unknown block</p>' . "\n";
        break;
    }
    //echo $out;
    return $out;
}

//addBlock(1);
echo addBlock(1);
//Раскомментить для выбора способа вывода
//Неплохой способ, если нужно обрабатывать исключения
```

---

```
function addBlock($block){//Более приятный способ, без кейсов и громоздкого синтаксиса
    $out = array(
        1 => "<p class=\"block-one\">$text1</p>\n
              <p class=\"block-two\">$text2</p>\n",
        2 => "<p class=\"block-three\">$text3</p>\n
              <p class=\"block-four\">$text4</p>\n",
    );
    return array_key_exists($block,$out) ? $out[$block] : FALSE ;//Проверяем есть ли такой блок в массиве, и возвращаем, если есть, либо кидаем FALSE
}
```

Comment: А если блоков будет в разы больше?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а если блоки будут не статичны а динамические, а если блоки будут не `1,2,3`, а `'service, support, market'`, и т.д. Решение подбирается под конкретную реализацию, масштабы которой в конкретном случае неясны. Если у вас есть вариант куда как более удобный и качественный, я думаю вы знакомы с кнопкой `Отправьте ваш ответ`

Comment: Я совсем забыл о кейсах. Спасибо, сделал.

Answer (score 1):

1) Почитать об [условных операторах](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.elseif.php).

2) Не забыть что если вы выводите (вызываете echo) внутри функции, то этого не нужно делать для самой функции.Либо функция должна возвращать строку

```
public function string_by_condition($cond){
    var str = '';
    if($cond== 1){
        str .='Строка 1';
        str .='Строка 2';   
    } else if($cond==2) {
        str .='Строка 3';
        str .='Строка 4';
    } else {...}

    return $str
}

echo string_by_condition(1);
```

В вашем случае возможно лучше передать параметры и собрать строку

```
public function createBlcok($class1,$class2,text1,text2){
    return  "<p class=\"$class1\">$text1</p><p class=\"$class2\">$text2</p>";
}
```

Comment: А если блоков будет 50 - вот веселье понесётся

Comment: Цель была ответить на вопрос, и показать человеку в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: Проблема в том, что если количество блоков может варьироваться и увеличиваться в сторону бесконечности, то это будет неправильная сторона

Comment: Так устроит отца русской Демократии ?

Comment: теоретически можно еще лучше сделать)) но это уже яяявно лучше.... кстати, чтоб нее заморачиваться с бэкслешами можно внутри ставить одинарные. и красивее будет и удобнее

Comment: Тут ты не прав :) В браузер попадут одинарные, и там то может возникнуть и проблема, например если это был не класс а атрибут и ты будешь обращаться к нему так $('input[name="somename"]'), оне не найдется :)

Comment: каким образом в браузер попадут одинарные?

Comment: А ты про какие кавычки про внешние ? или внутренние ?

Comment: Про внутренние `"<p class='$test'>text1</p><p class='$test2'>text2</p>";`

Comment: "class='$class'" - вот так если попадут одинарные, а если так ' class="'.$class.'"' писать надо :)

Comment: Еще раз спрошу: откуда вдруг внезапно возникнут одинарные кавычки? выполните код `$test = 'hello';
$test2 = 'hello2';
echo "<p class='$test'>tets1</p><p class='$test2'>tesxt2</p>";` и посмотрите в инспектор.. вы увидите там одинарные кавычки?

Comment: Че ходил проверял :), ну это просто тебе браузер преобразовал, при первоначальной загрузке, а пришли этот текст через ajax и вставь на страницу )

Comment: Ну во-первых мы начали с цитирую: `Тут ты не прав :) В браузер попадут одинарные`..... ни про какие аяксы ты не упомянул ;-)  ..... но и да... после получения от аякса эту строку ты в любом случае вставляешь в шаблон, утрированно говоря `success: function(response){    
 console.log(response);
 $('body').append(response); 
  }` иииии....магия....  смотрим....будут ли там одинарные кавычки ;-)  то есть итоговый контейнер - браузер........и никаких одинарников там нет..в данном случае

Comment: Как ты считаешь если бы я не сталкивался с таким, я бы тут об этом писал ? И вообще я думаю это не имеет отношение к этому вопросу.

Comment: Я считаю, что ты с этим сталкивался потому, что делал что-то не так ;-)   .... ты сам начал, говоря что я не прав :-P

Comment: а чего ссылку на [обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50602/discussion-between-orange-shadow-and--) удалил? :D